# Convert enum in JSON response to enum in protobuf

Tags: c++, enums, protocol-buffers

I am working on a project with REST api and response is in JSON format. One of the field in the response is a enum. So response schema for the field looks something like:

```
...
"state" : {
  "enum" : {
    "active",
    "deleting"
  }
  "type" : "string"
}
...
```

The actual response would look something like this:

```
{
  ...
  "state" : "active",
  ...
}
```

I have to define a proto message for this response, but am wondering if I could have a `state` field as a enum in the proto. And if we can, how would be the enum be defined in the proto message.

Paste of complete JSON response schema: https://pastebin.com/htH2Ln7f

Paste of complete JSON response: https://pastebin.com/WdnreFLr

Comment: Your sample still does not match your patebin JSON

Comment: @ArtemyVysotsky It does. There are 2 parts: a response schema and response. could you please check again. I have also included the complete response schema and response.